# Apex Batch Size Error - AsyncApexExecutions Limit exceeded

Tags: apex, batch, governorlimits

I have written a Batch Class which will Map Contact Object to lead Object. I have 6,000,000 which will be Mapped to Lead (like i am creating Lead using Contact Details). But when I am running the Batch with Size 1 it is giving me the Following Error:

> AsyncApexExecutions Limit exceeded.

How can I resolve  the above exception?

Comment: not sure but this could be reason http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/63858/18731

Comment: @ShantanuMahajan Did you check https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000948aIAA ?

Comment: @Arvind Yes I have checked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible cause is you are hitting governor limits for Async transactions

[Per the doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm), the limit is:

> 250,000 or the number of user licenses in your organization multiplied
>   by 200, whichever is greater

So, if you had 100 user seats, your limit is 250,000 - 2 = 249,998 `execute()` invocations.

*(-2 because the `start()` and `finish()` consume one async transaction each)*

If you had 10,000 user seats, your limit is 1,999,998 `execute()` invocations.

With 6,000,000 records processed with batch size = 1, you would need a user org of 30,001 seats.

*And, this assumes that during the 24 hour period, no other async job consumes async resources.*

Suggested solution is to make the batch size bigger (like the default of 200).

An alternative solution would be to export all the Contacts to Excel, then use the Bulk API option of Data Loader to create Leads.

Comment: Can you just clarify why `-2`? Might also be worth mentioning the minimum viable batch size. (I think it's just `24`?)

Comment: @AdrianLarson - DONE (I put the -2 in because I knew one of you guys would jump on me for the calculations re: start and finish if I omitted it.  :-).  I'm not familiar with any minimum viable batch size.

Comment: In re: minimum viable batch size, I mean that it has to be more than `1`, but you don't have to bump it all the way up to `200`, necessarily. There is some minimum size that will work. with 6M records, if you max out at 250K, then you need to set it at least to `24`. If the numbers were exact, I guess you'd need `25` because of the `start` and `finish` calls).

Comment: @AdrianLarson - ah, I thought you meant some other SFDC feature.   If OP had 10,000 user seats, then MVBS = 4. But main point is batch size of 1 is problematic and I'll trust OP to use basic arithmetic to decide what to do next.

Comment: In my experience 10k seats is a pretty big org. I guess it depends on how many communities you have set up...

Comment: @AdrianLarson - N.B. `The licenses that count toward this limit are full Salesforce user licenses or Force.com App Subscription user licenses. Chatter Free, Chatter customer users, Customer Portal User, and partner portal User licenses aren’t included`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42663/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-cropredy).

Comment: @cropredy: Thanks a ton, you saved me from the pain to identify the cause of this generic message!